# Is there any way to create a stack through STL which contains elements of more than one data type?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, data-structures, stl

Is there any way to create a stack through STL which contains elements of more than one data type?  For e.g. I want to create a stack which accepts integer and character value.

Comment: You may be looking for `std::variant`

Answer (score 1):

The STL containers all contain elements of only a single type.

However, there are two ways that this requirement can be loosened.

The first is through a container of pointers where the types are related via inheritance. That isn't appropriate for what you're asking for here.

The second is (as Igor said above) to use `std::variant` to make a new type that can contain different types inside of itself.

So, for your example, you could do `std::stack<std::variant<int, char>>`.